# Object giving null error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am receiving this error **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**, i know the reason but however I don't know how to solve it. I tried adding this line

```
if (postingObj == null) {
                ViewBag.Message = "There is no transaction to be approved";
            }
```

But didn't work either; I would like to throw a error message instead.

```
public ActionResult TransactionList(List<TransactionIssues> postingObj)
    {
        IssueDAO dbObj = new IssueDAO(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TWCL_OPERATIONSConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        List<string> docNumbers = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in postingObj)
        {
            if (item.postTrnx)
            {
                docNumbers.Add(item.docNumber);
            }
        }
        if (docNumbers.Count == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Please select at least one Transaction to Approve";
            return View(dbObj.GetAllTransactions());
        }

        dbObj.SetStatus0(docNumbers);
        ViewBag.Message = "Approval Successful!";
        return View(dbObj.GetAllTransactions());
    }
```

Comment: where are you getting the error? before the loop? if thats the case, make sure postingObj is initialized before calling the method, or your check for null is before the loop.

Comment: I'm getting the error right at the loop  foreach (var item in postingObj); I was just trying this if (postingObj == null) {
                ViewBag.Message = "There is no transaction to be approved";
            } when received the error but it didn't work either

Comment: Can you suggest an answer to how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you get rid of the error, without knowing your objects, I can suggest this before the loop:

```
if (postingObj == null) {
    postingObj = new List<TransactionIssues>();
}
```

Or this, if you dont depend on postingObj:

```
if (postingObj == null) {
    ViewBag.Message = "There is no transaction to be approved";
    return View(dbObj.GetAllTransactions());
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to help me solve this one; @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.processedbyDetails.employeeNum, new SelectList(ViewBag.StoresReps, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" }) same issue about null

Comment: Im guessing:
if (model.processedbyDetails==null){model.processedbyDetails= new ClassthatprocesseddetailsIs(); }